# stata: remove everything after the last occurrence of a specified character

Tags: stata

My data is like this

Var
A (c) | B(/ c/) | C.c
F | G9
K | S | V | S
F | A

I want to get everything before the last occurrence of the character "|" in Stata, like follows:

NewVar
Var
A (c) | B(/ c/) |
F |
K | S | V |
F |

```
egen NewVar=ends(Var), punct(|) last trim
```

can give me everything after the last occurrence of the character "|". But I have not found a way to get everything before the last occurrence of a character. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
clear 
input str21 Var
"A (c) | B(/ c/) | C.c"
"F | G9"
"K | S | V | S"
"F | A"
end 

gen Wanted = reverse(substr(reverse(Var),strpos(reverse(Var), "|"), . ))
l

     +-------------------------------------------+
     |                   Var              Wanted |
     |-------------------------------------------|
  1. | A (c) | B(/ c/) | C.c   A (c) | B(/ c/) | |
  2. |                F | G9                 F | |
  3. |         K | S | V | S         K | S | V | |
  4. |                 F | A                 F | |
     +-------------------------------------------+
```

A port of first call here for such problems is [the help for string functions](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?string%20functions). The solution above has been possible since early versions of Stata (with the proviso that `strpos()` was earlier known as `index()`).

Another solution would make use of the more recently added function `strrpos()`

```
gen Wanted2 = substr(Var, 1, strrpos(Var, "|"))
```

which for most tastes is likely to seem more direct and congenial.